# CSS box-shadow hidden (z-index does not fix)

Tags: z-index, css

I have a box-shadow on my `#primaryNav` div. Unfortunately, the shadow is being covered/hidden by the background of the following `#page` element.

I tried to set a z-index of 100 to `#primaryNav` and a z-index of -100 to #page, but that does not fix my problem.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Where should this shadow be, on the top or bottom of the nav?

Answer (score 121):

You need to define positioning for `#primaryNav`. Z-index only affects positioned elements.
I just added this in firebug and it fixed:

```
#primaryNav {
  position: relative;
 }
```

I would avoid using a negative z-index. Simply change z-index of `#page` to 0.

Comment: Perfect. Didn't know that about z-index & positioned elements. Thanks so much.

Comment: this is the correct answer. OP should mark it accordingly

Comment: This is brilliant,  ive known about z-index but you are the first person that I have come across that has explained that positioning is required for it to work, thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you man. This worked like a charm and you fulled a gap in my knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

As jlego already said a relative position should fix it.
By the way I would suggest ensuring that there is no shadow left or right of the `#primaryNav`. Since `#primaryNav` has a width of 100% a shadow on the side makes a horizontal scrollbar appear.

For fixing this you could set a `overflow:hidden` to `#iframe`

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at your site and I think the `border-bottom` property of `#primaryNav` is covering up your shadow.